# Emacs application doesn't play well with emacs daemon

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon

Using the zsh function

```
emacs () {
  visible_frames () {
    emacsclient -a "" -e '(length (visible-frame-list))'
  }
  change_focus () {
    emacsclient -n -e "(select-frame-set-input-focus (selected-frame))" > /dev/null
  }
  test "$(visible_frames)" -eq "1" && change_focus
  if [ "$(visible_frames)" -lt "2" ]
  then
    emacsclient -n -c "$@" && change_focus
  else
    change_focus
    test "$#" -ne "0" && emacsclient -n "$@"
  fi
}
```

I can visit a file in an emacs frame using `emacs foo`, and start a server if there isn't one already running. That works great. But two things don't really work well:

1. I have git's `core.editor` set to `emacs`, but that doesn't seem to invoke my script. Is that because the autoload for the emacs function is in my `zshrc`, which doesn't get invoked for a noninteractive shell? How should I deal with this?
2. When I simply click the application icon in the Applications folder, it invokes a standalone emacs, which then complains that it is not connected to the running server. How to make this work?

In both cases, the result is usable; it's just messy, and I'd like it to work properly.

Edit: This is Emacs 28.2 on MacOS 11.7.1.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a question about your operating system, not Emacs. When Git runs a program like Emacs, it doesn’t open a shell and type in “emacs”, so of course it doesn’t end up running your function. Same with the OS shell; when you click on an Emacs icon it runs the Emacs application; it doesn’t go looking for your function.

You should instead create a shell script called `emacs` and put it in your `PATH` ahead of the real Emacs. Then Git will find your script when it needs to run Emacs. You could also tell Git to run the script by specifying the full path to it.

You can do something similar with your OS shell by dragging the script into the dock so that you can run it directly. I don’t use OSX, so you should consult its documentation if you have any questions.

Comment: i do use macOS and @db48x nailed. if you want emacs "always up" you can run the emacs server via `launchd` and then always connect via `emacsclient`. google is your friend for this setup.